# Updating Android app's description after it's been published

Tags: android

Is it possible to add a list of known bugs to the description of an Android app in Google Play store after it's been published without forcing an app's update, i.e. no new version of the APK.

Comment: just add the new description.It will be updated soon.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can just to the Play Market console, and change your description (or better in your case, list the things you want in the update section).

You don't have to deploy a new build to change the description - it can be done at any time.